# Are there Animation Layers?

Tags: animation, graph-editor, actions

That's it. Coming from Maya, I just want to know how people do animation layers in blender. All of the articles that I've seen are either outdated or don't actually have to do with layers and they get it mixed up.

Comment: I guess what you're searching for is the NLA Editor. You can also bake down the strips: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/strips.html#action-strips

Comment: Damn I didn't even know this was a thing. When did it get added?

Comment: Not sure, 10-15 years ago? We can do a search for the actual commit...